# Why Makefile include should be after all: target?

Tags: makefile

I've been using Makefile and to keep some stuff sepparate I decided to include a new common makefile. The problem I faced is that my First makefile looks like this:

Filename Makefile.test

```
include ./Makefile.a
all: a b c
b:
    @echo "b"
c:
    @echo "c"
```

Filename Makefile.a

```
a:
    @echo "a"
```

When I execute my makefile: make -f Makefile.test I only get "a" printed out and it finishes.

The only way to make it work is place the include bellow (anywhere) the all: target

Is there a reason why this behaves liks this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say this:

```
include ./Makefile.a
```

make just pulls `Makefile.a` into the current Makefile in the same way that `#include <x.h>` does in C: it inserts the contents of `Makefile.a` to replace the `include` statement and keeps going. The result is that make sees this when it starts figuring out what to do:

```
a:
    @echo "a"
all: a b c
b:
    @echo "b"
c:
    @echo "c"
```

So the first target in source-order will be `a` and since you didn't specify a target, make will use the first one. That's where your result comes from.

You could explicitly specify the `all` target if you wanted:

```
make -f Makefile.test all
```

That would use the `all` target regardless of where it appears in the Makefile.

If you're using GNU Make, then you could use [`.DEFAULT_GOAL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables) to specify a default target inside `Makefile.test` and then you wouldn't have to worry about the order:

```
include ./Makefile.a
all: a b c
b:
    @echo "b"
c:
    @echo "c"

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

Thanks to [Idelic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109744/idelic) for the reminder about this.

Comment: If using GNU make, you could also override the default target in `Makefile.test` by setting `.DEFAULT_GOAL := all`.

Comment: @Idelic: Thanks for the reminder, been awhile since I've done any serious make work.